# How to publish a npm module without any babel dependency?

Tags: node.js, npm, babeljs

I am building a npm project(moduleA) and will publish to npm registry. It uses javascript with `webpack4` and `babel7`. It works fine by itself but there is some babel problems when I try to test the project from a different module. The test project is using `babel 6.26.3` with `webpack2`. When I build the test project I get below error:

```
ERROR in /Users/dev/moduleA/build/index.js
Module build failed: Error: Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded
 with "6.26.3". If you are sure you have a compatible version of 
@babel/core, it is likely that something in your build process is loading 
the wrong version. Inspect the stack trace of this error to look for the 
first entry that doesn't mention "@babel/core" or "babel-core" to see what 
is calling Babel.
```

The first line in the error output above is about the `moduleA` package which has babel7 dependency. I expect the build artefact from `moduleA` should not include any information about babel. But it looks like `moduleA` brings babel7 to the test project which conflict with the test project babel6. How can I solve this problem in moduleA?

Below is `moduleA` babelrc config:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-export-default-from",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from"
  ]
}
```

the babel dependencies in `moduleA` is:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-export-default-from": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/preset-es2015": "^7.0.0-beta.53",
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to split the files that you're shipping into two: `src` and `dist`.

`src` will contain the original code that requires Babel and Webpack in order to get it running.

`dist` is the compiled version, most likely ES5 code that is able to run without using Babel or Webpack.

Refer to Webpack documentation to create a compiled version that's optimized for production: https://webpack.js.org/guides/production

After you've managed to get your code compiled, use the `main` attribute in the `package.json` file to point to the compiled version and not to the source (original) version.